# Removing and setting cookie simultaneously in Silex/Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, cookies, silex

Is it possible to remove a cookie and set one with the same name but different value in one request? Here is the code I have so far, which works locally for me but not on the live server. The cookie is set from a query string and sometimes the cookie can be set externally (not HttpOnly), but on the live server, I will get a redirect loop and both cookies will be set.

```
if ($request->query->has('cookie')) {
    $setCookie = $request->query->get('cookie');
    $route = $request->getRequestUri();
    $host = $request->getHost();

    if (!$request->cookies->has('reference') || $request->cookies->get('reference') !== $setCookie){
        $exp = new \DateTime();
        $exp->modify('+3 months'); // cookie has three months to live
        $r = new RedirectResponse($route);
        $r->headers->clearCookie('reference');
        $r->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('reference', $setCookie, $exp, '/', $host));
        return $r;
    }
}
```

So if the user goes to www.*******.com/?cookie=newvalue, I need any current cookie with the name 'reference' and a new cookie set with the value, 'newvalue'.